# Proving Young's Theorem with a lemma (symmetry of partial derivatives)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Young's theorem: for a function $f: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ which has continuous partial derivatives we have htat $f_{ij}(a) = f_{ji}(a)$ for $a \in A \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ with $A$ open.

I have proved the following lemma:

for $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ with continuous partial derivatives we have $f_{xy}(a) = f_{yx}(a)$ for $a \in A$ open as above.

How can I use the lemma to prove the theorem? Is there a shortcut?

I proved the lemma by considering $f_{xy}(a) - f_{yx}(a) > 0$ and using Fubini's Theorem for a contradiction. Similarly for $f_{xy} - f_{yx} < 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**
Let $f:\mathbb {R}^n\to R$, we want to show that $f_{ij}=f_{ji}$. WLOG $i<j$. Define $g^\alpha:\mathbb {R}^2\to R$ as following 
$$g^\alpha(x,y)=f(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{i-1},x,\alpha_{i+1},...,\alpha_{j-1},y,\alpha_{j+1},...,\alpha_n)
$$

Conclude Young's theorem from $g^\alpha_{xy}=g^\alpha_{yx}$ which you have already proved.